# Where do i define the test contract params?

Tags: truffle, ethereumj, mocha

lets say i have this code (taken from [here](http://truffleframework.com/docs/getting_started/javascript-tests))

```
// Specifically request an abstraction for MetaCoin
var MetaCoin = artifacts.require("MetaCoin");

contract('MetaCoin', function(accounts) {
it("should put 10000 MetaCoin in the first account", function() {
  return MetaCoin.deployed().then(function(instance) {
    return instance.getBalance.call(accounts[0]);
```

where do i config the  "accounts" param - i couldnt find a clear definition anywhere - 10x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the Truffle documentation explains:

> The contract() function provides a list of available
>   accounts as a second parameter with which you can write tests against.

You don't have to config the accounts params. If you are testing the contract in testrpc, the accounts passed will be those that got generated in testrpc.

Comment: what about all other params i wanna add? owner and whatever i can think of...

Comment: ok, afaik you can declare general "accounts" array, or declare different aliases for the accounts you defined (or got by default) in your test rpc (of some kind)